# I need a video upload service which has SDK support

Tags: video, upload, youtube, cloud, vimeo

I need a video upload service which has SDK support. I need to upload approximately 15-20K videos. (per size about to 100mb)

In the service I'm looking for, able to upload on code-behind, reach easily and playing fast. Users can upload with my application.

I examined some services such as youtube, vimeo, dailymotion. They have some disadvantages or advantages.

Did you use any services like this which has my particular needs ?

Comment: What language does the SDK need to be in? Vimeo offers official PHP, Python and node libraries, and has third party JS, .net and java libraries.

Comment: I need for IOS, objective-c SDK

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try [Brightcove](https://www.brightcove.com/en/online-video-platform)? I have never used them myself but I know lots of popular sites do.